# Linking to other pages on Simple R markdown website

Tags: r, r-markdown, netlify

I'm developing a Simple R Markdown Website, and want to include a few links to other .Rmd generated HTML pages on the home page.

Simply, I want to open up "detailed-desc.html" which is rendered from "detailed-desc.Rmd", on clicking a text element on the "index.Rmd" file. I'm not sure how this can be done.

Answer (score 1):

If all your .Rmd files and their rendered HTML results are in the same directory, then you can use the regular markdown syntax and reference the HTML files for links.

```
[Detailed Description](detailed-desc.html)
```

Detailed Description

With a more complicated site folder structure, it is just

```
[Detailed Description](./path/to/your/folder/detailed-desc.html)
```

Detailed Description

Comment: when the .Rmd file and the rendered HTML file are in the same directory [Detailed Description](detailed-desc.html) works
However, when the .Rmd file is moved into a sub folder, the render_site() function doesn't render it into an HTML file

Comment: You are right, rmarkdown in general handles applying common options/elements across subdirectories poorly. It is required all of the files to `render_site` live in the default "." or the single path you specify -- search for Rmds to render is not recursive. 

However, there is nothing stopping you from putting subfolders into that structure -- either created by R code or static -- that also contain content. I just wanted to make sure the syntax was there.